# SQL Server 2014 Avaliability Group DbMgrPartnerCommitPolicy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, error-log

I have an environment with 2 Windows Server 2012 R2 servers, both with SQL Server 2014 Expensive edition.

Whenever a change happens in the AGs (such as: AlwaysOn Availability Groups connection with secondary database established for primary database 'AGDatabase' on the availability replica 'SecondaryReplicaThatIRestarted'), I get an error like this, in my SQL error log:

> Source: SPID52s
>
> Message
>   DbMgrPartnerCommitPolicy::SetSyncState:00000003BFC0B0E0:1

Ending with a result like this:

[Imgur: Screenshot of the errorlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw7Vm.png)

**EDIT:**

Nothing in the Windows Error log, not even the mentioned error, which leads me to believe it's something SQL internal that's being leaked out into the errorlog.

Any ideas of what this could be caused by? I've set up multiple setups similiar to this, and this is the first time I've seen it. 
I plan on patching the SQL to SP1 this week, however I don't see the error in the release notes.

Comment: Did you check windows event log ? Also, can you post the exact error with error number ? Any chance you did a force failover ?

Comment: @Kin Updated - Also I didn't do a forced failover. Both AG's were running on Node1, then I rebooted Node2 (Secondary Sync commit) for maintenance. But it happens every time any state changes happens.

Comment: Let us know if the latest patch addresses the problem. I have not seen this in my environment.. So just curious to know.

Answer (score 5):

For future readers :

DbMgrPartnerCommitPolicy::SetSyncState:00000003BFC0B0E0:**1**

The last integer describes the AG state

```
0 - Not Joined to AG
1 - Not Synchronized
2 - Suspended
4 - Synchronized
8 - Redo (redoing log)
```

Ref : [DbMgrPartnerCommitPolicy::SetSyncState May Seem More Mysterious than It Actually Is](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/dbmgrpartnercommitpolicy-setsyncstate-may-seem-more-mysterious/ba-p/334007)